# StackOverflowError running JUnit with Ant 1.9.3

Tags: ant, ant-junit

Every now and then when I run my JUnit report generation with Ant 1.9.3 and Java 1.8.0_91 it fails with a StackOverflowError with no apparent reason. I've spend many hours trying to pinpoint what causes this but have had no luck so far.

Any ideas on how fix / workaround this?

```
[junitreport] Processing /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/mytest/reports/TESTS-TestSuites.xml to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/mytest/reports/junit-noframes.html
[junitreport] Loading stylesheet jar:file:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-junit.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/junit/xsl/junit-noframes.xsl
[junitreport] Warning:  org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser: Property 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD' is not recognized.
[junitreport] Warning:  org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser: Property 'http://www.oracle.com/xml/jaxp/properties/entityExpansionLimit' is not recognized.

BUILD FAILED
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/mytest/build.xml:357: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToHTMLStream$Trie.get2(ToHTMLStream.java:2291)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToHTMLStream.getElemDesc2(ToHTMLStream.java:633)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToHTMLStream.startElement(ToHTMLStream.java:795)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToStream.startElement(ToStream.java:1853)
    at junit_noframes.br$dash$replace()
    at junit_noframes.br$dash$replace()
    at junit_noframes.br$dash$replace()
    at junit_noframes.br$dash$replace()
    at junit_noframes.br$dash$replace()
    at junit_noframes.br$dash$replace()
```

Comment: Could you please provide the version of ant?

Comment: Added version info to the question and after looking into that version history found that it's a bug fixed in 1.9.4. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is a known [bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57341) with ant and was fixed in 1.9.4. Upgrading ant to 1.9.7. fixed the problem for me!